# How check deferred transaction logs on EOS jungle testnet?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, testnet

As I working on jungle testnet and perform a 1 deferred transaction with some scheduled automatic time. But I failed to see transaction logs on the jungle testnet.

Can any please guide me here with any command?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for your transaction on https://jungle.eosq.eosnation.io/ Just type in the transaction id.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the transaction using `cleos` by typing:

```
cleos get transaction TRANSACTION_ID
```

For future updates on the use of this command, see https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.0/cleos/how-to-guides/how-to-get-transaction-information